# How to Declare Objects by Using Defined Names

Tags: excel, vba, vba7, vba6

Disclaimer: I am still very new to VBA so hoping for your patience

I am trying to write a code that uses Range("*Defined Name")* instead of Range(*"Cell Address"*)

However, I keep encountering errors. In this code for example, I am trying to set the Source Document and the Destination Document by using the Workbook/Worksheet name I input in a cell

What I tried:
*assume content of cell is also their Defined Name and this table is in Destination Workbook where the VBA code is also embedded in

|  | A (Filepath) | B (Name of Worksheets) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SourceWB | SourceWS |
| 2 | DestinationWB | DestinationWS |

```
Sub ImportData()
    Dim WB_S as Workbook 'source workbook
    Dim WS_S as Worksheet 'source worksheet
    Dim WB_D as Workbook 'destination workbook
    Dim WS_D as Worksheet 'destination worksheet


    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'OpenWorksheets

    Set WB_D = Workbooks.Open(Range("DestinationWB")) 'referring to A2
    Set WS_D = WB_D.Sheets(Range("DestinationWS")) 'referring to B2 'ERROR
    Set WB_S = Workbooks.Open(Range("SourceWB")) 'referring to A1
    Set WS_S = WB_S.Sheets(WB_D.Range("DestinationWS")) 'referring to B2 'referring to B1
```

I get error as soon as I reach line where I `Set WS_D`

Again, my goal is to refer to the file path and name of worksheets as the Defined Names

Thank you for your help

Comment: After opening the workbook, the active workbook changes so Range("DestinationWS) I assume is in the workbook with the code? Try ThisWorkkbook.Range("DestinationWS)

Comment: Qualify the range calls with the relevant worksheet. Otherwise, `Range("DestinationWS")` is evaluated in the context of the active workbook, which is changed as soon as you open the other workbook on the preceding line.

Comment: You miss the closing quotes after `"DestinationWS`.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for the response. 

On:
- missing closing quotes, fixed it.
- "Thisworkbook.Range" still didn't work
- Although I opened Destination Workbook, it is actually where the Range calls is referred to. Thus WB_D.Sheets(Range("DestinationWS))

Comment: error says "Type mismatch" :(

Comment: You're still leaving out the closing quotes, i.e. `Set WS_D = WB_D.Sheets(Range("DestinationWS"))` instead of `Set WS_D = WB_D.Sheets(Range("DestinationWS))`. You shouldn't need to open the destinationworkbook as that is the one where you're working from.

Comment: Are the named ranges scoped to Workbook or Worksheet ?

Comment: Defined Names and Range "A1" or "R1C1" formulas are analogues. Since in the NameManager you see that `RefersTo`

Comment: Hi @CDP1802 it is scoped to Workbook

Comment: How can you open the same workbook without a warning message?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportData()
    Dim WB_S As Workbook 'source workbook
    Dim WS_S As Worksheet 'source worksheet
    Dim WB_D As Workbook 'destination workbook
    Dim WS_D As Worksheet 'destination worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet, nm, msg As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ' check named ranges
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet ' workbook where ranges are defined
    For Each nm In Array("SourceWB", "SourceWS", "DestinationWB", "DestinationWS")
        On Error Resume Next
        If ws.Range(nm) Is Nothing Then
             MsgBox "'" & nm & "' is not a named range", vbCritical
             Exit Sub
        Else
             msg = msg & vbLf & nm & " - " & ws.Range(nm)
        End If
        On Error Goto 0
    Next
    
    'OpenWorksheets
    Set WB_D = Workbooks.Open(ws.Range("DestinationWB")) 'referring to A2
    Set WS_D = WB_D.Sheets(ws.Range("DestinationWS").Value2) 'referring to B2
    
    Set WB_S = Workbooks.Open(ws.Range("SourceWB")) 'referring to A1
    Set WS_S = WB_S.Sheets(ws.Range("SourceWS").Value2) 'referring to B1
    
    MsgBox msg, vbInformation
End Sub
```